# Get records where join table ids don't match ids in text strings

Tags: mysql

I've got two tables and want to find out the rows in one table with no corresponding ids and rows in another table. Unfortunately the ids of the first table are included in the second as text strings:
table "files" with column file_id and table "product_desc" with column description in which the file_ids are included as strings like "file==7". None, one or several file_ids per string can be included.

I am looking for those rows of "product_desc" where file_id is missing in "files". In this little example it would be the "product_desc" with id 6 because there is no file with file_id=5 in table "files":

table "files"

```
file_id
1
2
10
```

table "product_desc"

```
id | description
3  | bla bla file==1 bla bla file==2 bla bla    
6  | bla bla blub file==5 bla bla file==10 bla bla 
7  | bla bla file==2 bla bla
```

Probably I need substring functions, but I don't know how. Something like

```
SELECT id FROM product_desc LEFT JOIN files ON id LIKE CONCAT '%file==',file_id,'%') WHERE file_id IS NULL
```

Thank you very much for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your attempt is pretty good.  This comes close:

```
SELECT pd.id
FROM product_desc pd LEFT JOIN
     files f
     ON pd.description LIKE CONCAT('%file==', f.file_id, '%')
WHERE f.file_id IS NULL;
```

The problem is that if one matches and one is missing, then you will not get the product description record.  So, this finds the cases where *all* file ids in the description are missing.

If you assume that the file ids are all different in any given description, then you can use this hack to get what you want:

```
SELECT pd.id
FROM product_desc pd LEFT JOIN
     files f
     ON pd.description LIKE CONCAT('%file==', f.file_id, '%')
GROUP BY pd.id
HAVING COUNT(f.file_id) = (LENGTH(pd.description) -
                           LENGTH(REPLACE(pd.description, 'file==', 'file='))
                          );
```

The `HAVING` clause counts the number of times that `file==` appears in the description, by replacing each occurrence with a string one character shorter.  This should match the number that match the `ON` clause, otherwise one is missing.

Comment: Thank you, Gordon - it was exactly my problem that the field ids are all different.

Comment: (sorry, clicked to fast) - I had to do a little enhancement to the select-query: 
    SELECT pd.id, length(pd.description)
otherwise it returns an error 'Unknown column 'pd.description' in 'having clause'